# como funciona uma função "const void *foo( param, param)"?

Tags: funções, ponteiro, genéricos

```js
bool cmp(const void * a, const void * b) {
  return static_cast < /*type?*/ * > a < static_cast < /*type?*/ * > b;
}

const void * min(const void * first, const void * last, size_t size, compare cmp) {
  void * minor = * first;
  while (first != last) {
    if (cmp(first, first++)) {
      * minor = * first;
    }

    * first++;
  }
}
```

Estou tentado fazer uma função que a saída é a primeira ocorrência de do menor elemento, e o protótipo da função é

```
const void * min(const void * first, const void * last, size_t size, Compare cmp);
```

sendo que preciso programar a função cmp que retorna true se a < b e o protótipo tem que ser

```
bool cml ( const void * a, const void * b);
```

obs: o código tem q ser feito em c++

Comment: Não entendi bem o que está perguntando. quer saber como é a função que é passada como parâmetro?

Comment: também não entendi muito bem, vc quer entender por que o tipo de retorno é const void *? Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://www.quora.com/What-does-a-function-with-return-type-void*-return)